# Plotting a disk with a z-value different to zero

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, computational-geometry

I'm plotting a disk with `ParametricPlot3d`, but I need it to be drawn at `z = 0.4`, in order to join it with another plot.

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {r*Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[ϕ], r*Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[ϕ], r*Cos[Pi/2]},
  {r, 0, 1}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi},
  Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

This is the result joining it with the other graph:

[image]

I tried with `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0.4, 1}}` but that just set the way it is graphed, doesn´t solve the problem:

[image]

I just need the disk to be graphed at `z = 0.4` instead of `z = 0`.

Please help.

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D[{r*Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[\[Phi]], r*Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[\[Phi]], 
  0.4}, {r, 0, 1}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, Mesh -> None]`

Comment: @BobHanlon You should post that as an answer, I presume it will be accepted since  your answer has already been incorporated [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207759/731).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the `BoxRatios` you can see a cone rather than a disk. The cone is essentially at `0`. It looks like a cone due to machine precision in calculating `r*Cos[Pi/2]` which is exactly `0`.

```
r*Cos[Pi/2]

(* 0 *)

ParametricPlot3D[{r*Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[ϕ], r*Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[ϕ], 
  r*Cos[Pi/2]}, {r, 0, 1}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Your disc is exactly at `0` if you `Evaluate` the argument.

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@{r*Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[ϕ], r*Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[ϕ], 
   r*Cos[Pi/2]}, {r, 0, 1}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

To draw a disc at `z == 0.4` specify the `z` function as a constant.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r*Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[ϕ], r*Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[ϕ], 0.4}, {r, 
  0, 1}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]