# Making cuts in a paraboloid of revolution modified

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, computational-geometry

I need my to have like parabolic holes where the bumps or fins are ubicated, like in this image, so that they match with the same fins or bumps:

[image]

The graphic I have was done with a paraboloid and the bumps with bezier functions. I just join the individual graphics in order to have the whole one:

```
par = ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 -z == 0,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,0.4,1},
ClipPlanes ->InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0.4}, {1, 1, 0.4}, {0, 0, 0.4}}],
 ClipPlanesStyle ->Directive[Opacity[0.3], White], Mesh ->None]

circ =ParametricPlot3D[{r*Sin[Pi/2]*Cos[\[Phi]], r*Sin[Pi/2]*Sin[\[Phi]], 0.4}, {r, 0, Sqrt[0.4]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi}, Mesh -> None] 

pts = {{{-0.5, 0.88, 1}, {0, 1.4, 1}, {0, 1.4, 1}, {0.5, 0.88, 1}},
{{-0.45, 0.8, 0.85}, {-0.2,1.2, 0.85}, {0.2, 1.2, 0.85}, {0.45, 0.8, 0.85}},
{{-0.45, 0.75, 0.7}, {-0.2, 1.15, 0.7}, {0.2, 1.15, 0.7}, {0.45, 0.75, 0.7}},
{{-0.15, 0.76, 0.6}, {-0.08, 0.79, 0.62}, {0.08, 0.79, 0.62}, {0.15, 0.76, 0.6}}};

ptsdos = {{{-0.5, -0.88, 1}, {0, -1.4, 1}, {0, -1.4, 1}, {0.5, -0.88, 1}},
{{-0.45,- 0.8, 0.85}, {-0.2,-1.2, 0.85}, {0.2, -1.2, 0.85}, {0.45, -0.8, 0.85}},
{{-0.45,- 0.75, 0.7}, {-0.2, -1.15, 0.7}, {0.2, -1.15, 0.7}, {0.45, -0.75, 0.7}},
{{-0.15, -0.76, 0.6}, {-0.08, -0.79, 0.62}, {0.08, -0.79, 0.62}, {0.15, -0.76, 0.6}}};

ptstres = {{{0.88,-0.5, 1}, {1.4,0,  1}, { 1.4,0, 1}, {0.88,0.5, 1}},
{{ 0.8, -0.45,0.85}, {1.2, -0.2,0.85}, { 1.2, 0.2,0.85}, { 0.8,0.45, 0.85}},
{{ 0.75,-0.45, 0.7}, { 1.15,-0.2, 0.7}, { 1.15,0.2, 0.7}, {0.75, 0.45, 0.7}},
{{ 0.76,-0.15, 0.6}, { 0.79, -0.08,0.62}, { 0.79, 0.08,0.62}, { 0.76, 0.15,0.6}}};

ptscuatro = {{{-0.88,-0.5, 1}, {-1.4,0,  1}, { -1.4,0, 1}, {-0.88,0.5, 1}},
{{ -0.8, -0.45,0.85}, {-1.2, -0.2,0.85}, { -1.2, 0.2,0.85}, { -0.8,0.45, 0.85}},
{{ -0.75,-0.45, 0.7}, { -1.15,-0.2, 0.7}, { -1.15,0.2, 0.7}, {-0.75, 0.45, 0.7}},
{{ -0.76,-0.15, 0.6}, { -0.79, -0.08,0.62}, { -0.79, 0.08,0.62}, { -0.76, 0.15,0.6}}};

f = BezierFunction[pts]
fdos = BezierFunction[ptsdos]
ftres =  BezierFunction[ptstres]
fcuatro = BezierFunction[ptscuatro]

p1 = ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None]
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[fdos[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None]
p3 = ParametricPlot3D[ftres[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None]
p4 = ParametricPlot3D[fcuatro[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None]

Show[p1,p2,p3,p4,par, circ]
```

And this is the final result:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be hard to get the contour surface to have an edge that matches the edge of the Bezier surface, so I'll present a different approach:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 (Max[0.6 z, (0.1 + 0.35 z^2) Abs@Sin[2 t]]) *   (* radius = Max[cyl, bump] *)
   {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + {0, 0, z},
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 1, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
 Exclusions -> None, MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image]

Next, we use an interpolation to control the radius of the bumps, and smooth out `Max` a little with a moving average near the edges:

```
ClearAll[smoothMax];
SetAttributes[smoothMax, HoldAll];
smoothMax[a_, b_, x_, dx_: 0.1] := Module[{aa, bb, mm},
   Block[{x, x0 = x},
    aa = Table[a, {x, {x0 - dx, x0, x0 + dx}}];
    bb = Table[b, {x, {x0 - dx, x0, x0 + dx}}];
    mm = Max /@ Transpose@{aa, bb};
    If[mm == aa,
     a,
     If[mm == bb,
      b,
      Mean[mm]
      ]]
    ]];

ParametricPlot3D[(smoothMax[
     0.25 (z - 0.2) (5 - z),
     InterpolatingPolynomial[{{1., 0., 0.5}, {1.6, 
         0.25 (1.6 - 0.2) (5 - 1.6)}, {2.3, 1.55, 0.5}, {3, 1.8, 0, 
         0}}, z] Sin[4 t],
     t, 0.01]) {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} + {0, 0, z},
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 1, 3},
 Mesh -> None, Exclusions -> None,
 PlotPoints -> {101, 25}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]